# RabbitMQ: Channel shutdown: connection error

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, connection-refused, connectionexception

I've setup rabbitmq with spring boot. Everything seems to be working fine in my local environment. But when I deploy it to production I'm getting this error:

```
31-05-2019 08:26:56.430 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] INFO  org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareConnection - Attempting to connect to: localhost:5672
31-05-2019 08:26:56.433 [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.log - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=541, reply-text=INTERNAL_ERROR, class-id=0, method-id=0)
31-05-2019 08:26:56.434 [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] WARN  com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler.log - An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connection reset)
31-05-2019 08:26:56.452 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] INFO  org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareConnection - Created new connection: connectionFactory#8139c95:2/SimpleConnection@4f0210ae [delegate=amqp://admin@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 47206]
31-05-2019 08:26:56.457 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-2] ERROR com.cinch.gch.core.config.GchExceptionHandler.handleAllOtherException - ExceptionHandler
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:113)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1473)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1423)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1399)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareExchange(RabbitAdmin.java:180)
        at com.cinch.gch.mailq.queue.ProducerConfiguration.<init>(ProducerConfiguration.java:41)
        at com.cinch.gch.mailq.queue.MQQueue.init(MQQueue.java:39)
        at com.cinch.gch.mailq.queue.MQQueue.<init>(MQQueue.java:25)
        at com.cinch.gch.mailq.service.MailService.send(MailService.java:42)
        at com.cinch.gch.mailq.controller.MailController.sendMails(MailController.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:854)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:765)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:193)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:124)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:120)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:142)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.exchangeDeclare(ChannelN.java:773)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.exchangeDeclare(ChannelN.java:53)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1029)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy564.exchangeDeclare(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareExchanges(RabbitAdmin.java:630)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.access$000(RabbitAdmin.java:72)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$1.doInRabbit(RabbitAdmin.java:184)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1467)
        ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=541, reply-text=INTERNAL_ERROR, class-id=0, method-id=0)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:443)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:263)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:136)
        ... 64 common frames omitted
31-05-2019 08:26:57.434 [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.log - Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown', class-id=0, method-id=0)
31-05-2019 08:26:57.444 [AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672] WARN  com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler.log - An unexpected connection driver error occured (Exception message: Connection reset)
```

Anyone have any idea what is about? Not posting code since it's working in local environment, and I believe it's because I'm missing something in the server side. If you think otherwise, let me know.

### Edit

Error occurs when I'm trying to create queues dynamically and add consumers. It seems the queues are created in the management console. but the listeners are not added.

### Edit

Rabbitmq logs

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:17 ===
** Generic server <0.627.0> terminating
** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',
                           {method,
                               {'exchange.declare',0,<<"mailq-exchange">>,
                                   <<"x-delayed-message">>,false,true,false,
                                   false,false,
                                   [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,
                                     <<"topic">>}]},
                               none,noflow}}
** When Server state == {ch,running,rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,1,<0.618.0>,
                            <0.625.0>,<0.618.0>,
                            <<"127.0.0.1:47239 -> 127.0.0.1:5672">>,
                            {lstate,<0.626.0>,false},
                            none,1,
                            {[],[]},
                            {user,<<"admin">>,
                                [administrator],
                                [{rabbit_auth_backend_internal,none}]},
                            <<"/">>,<<"q:17252337684797619970874926144232">>,
                            {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []},
                                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                  [],[]}}},
                            {state,
                                {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                    {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                     [],[],[]},
                                    {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                      [],[],[]}}},
                                erlang},
                            {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []},
                                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                  [],[]}}},
                            {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []},
                                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                  [],[]}}},
                            {set,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []},
                                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                  [],[]}}},
                            <0.620.0>,
                            {state,fine,5000,#Ref<0.0.0.30310>},
                            false,1,
                            {{0,nil},{0,nil}},
                            [],
                            {{0,nil},{0,nil}},
                            [{<<"exchange_exchange_bindings">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"connection.blocked">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"authentication_failure_close">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"basic.nack">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"publisher_confirms">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"consumer_cancel_notify">>,bool,true}],
                            none,0,none,flow,[]}
** Reason for termination == 
** {function_clause,
       [{rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message,validate,
            [{exchange,
                 {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"mailq-exchange">>},
                 'x-delayed-message',true,false,false,
                 [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,<<"topic">>}],
                 undefined,undefined,
                 {[],[]}}],
            [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message.erl"},{line,61}]},
        {rabbit_exchange,declare,6,
            [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,165}]},
        {rabbit_channel,handle_method,3,
            [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,1234}]},
        {rabbit_channel,handle_cast,2,
            [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,470}]},
        {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1047}]},
        {proc_lib,wake_up,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:17 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.618.0> (127.0.0.1:47239 -> 127.0.0.1:5672 - connectionFactory#8139c95:4, vhost: '/', user: 'admin', state: running), channel 1:
{function_clause,
    [{rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message,validate,
         [{exchange,
              {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"mailq-exchange">>},
              'x-delayed-message',true,false,false,
              [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,<<"topic">>}],
              undefined,undefined,
              {[],[]}}],
         [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message.erl"},{line,61}]},
     {rabbit_exchange,declare,6,[{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,165}]},
     {rabbit_channel,handle_method,3,
         [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,1234}]},
     {rabbit_channel,handle_cast,2,
         [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,470}]},
     {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1047}]},
     {proc_lib,wake_up,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}

=WARNING REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:17 ===
Non-AMQP exit reason '{function_clause,
                       [{rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message,validate,
                         [{exchange,
                           {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"mailq-exchange">>},
                           'x-delayed-message',true,false,false,
                           [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,<<"topic">>}],
                           undefined,undefined,
                           {[],[]}}],
                         [{file,
                           "src/rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message.erl"},
                          {line,61}]},
                        {rabbit_exchange,declare,6,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,165}]},
                        {rabbit_channel,handle_method,3,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,1234}]},
                        {rabbit_channel,handle_cast,2,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,470}]},
                        {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,
                         [{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1047}]},
                        {proc_lib,wake_up,3,
                         [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}'

=INFO REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:17 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1308.0> (127.0.0.1:47419 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:17 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.618.0> (127.0.0.1:47239 -> 127.0.0.1:5672 - connectionFactory#8139c95:4, vhost: '/', user: 'admin')

=INFO REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:17 ===
Connection <0.1308.0> (127.0.0.1:47419 -> 127.0.0.1:5672) has a client-provided name: connectionFactory#8139c95:5

=INFO REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:17 ===
connection <0.1308.0> (127.0.0.1:47419 -> 127.0.0.1:5672 - connectionFactory#8139c95:5): user 'admin' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'

=ERROR REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:28 ===
** Generic server <0.1316.0> terminating
** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',
                           {method,
                               {'exchange.declare',0,<<"mailq-exchange">>,
                                   <<"x-delayed-message">>,false,true,false,
                                   false,false,
                                   [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,
                                     <<"topic">>}]},
                               none,noflow}}
** When Server state == {ch,running,rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,1,<0.1308.0>,
                            <0.1314.0>,<0.1308.0>,
                            <<"127.0.0.1:47419 -> 127.0.0.1:5672">>,
                            {lstate,<0.1315.0>,false},
                            none,1,
                            {[],[]},
                            {user,<<"admin">>,
                                [administrator],
                                [{rabbit_auth_backend_internal,none}]},
                            <<"/">>,<<"q:20450439579894538978049880093722">>,
                            {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []},
                                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                  [],[]}}},
                            {state,
                                {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                    {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                     [],[],[]},
                                    {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                      [],[],[]}}},
                                erlang},
                            {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []},
                                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                  [],[]}}},
                            {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []},
                                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                  [],[]}}},
                            {set,0,16,16,8,80,48,
                                {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                 []},
                                {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                  [],[]}}},
                            <0.1309.0>,
                            {state,fine,5000,#Ref<0.0.0.30583>},
                            false,1,
                            {{0,nil},{0,nil}},
                            [],
                            {{0,nil},{0,nil}},
                            [{<<"exchange_exchange_bindings">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"connection.blocked">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"authentication_failure_close">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"basic.nack">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"publisher_confirms">>,bool,true},
                             {<<"consumer_cancel_notify">>,bool,true}],
                            none,0,none,flow,[]}
** Reason for termination == 
** {function_clause,
       [{rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message,validate,
            [{exchange,
                 {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"mailq-exchange">>},
                 'x-delayed-message',true,false,false,
                 [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,<<"topic">>}],
                 undefined,undefined,
                 {[],[]}}],
            [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message.erl"},{line,61}]},
        {rabbit_exchange,declare,6,
            [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,165}]},
        {rabbit_channel,handle_method,3,
            [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,1234}]},
        {rabbit_channel,handle_cast,2,
            [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,470}]},
        {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1047}]},
        {proc_lib,wake_up,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:28 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.1308.0> (127.0.0.1:47419 -> 127.0.0.1:5672 - connectionFactory#8139c95:5, vhost: '/', user: 'admin', state: running), channel 1:
{function_clause,
    [{rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message,validate,
         [{exchange,
              {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"mailq-exchange">>},
              'x-delayed-message',true,false,false,
              [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,<<"topic">>}],
              undefined,undefined,
              {[],[]}}],
         [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message.erl"},{line,61}]},
     {rabbit_exchange,declare,6,[{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,165}]},
     {rabbit_channel,handle_method,3,
         [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,1234}]},
     {rabbit_channel,handle_cast,2,
         [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,470}]},
     {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1047}]},
     {proc_lib,wake_up,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}

=WARNING REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:28 ===
Non-AMQP exit reason '{function_clause,
                       [{rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message,validate,
                         [{exchange,
                           {resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"mailq-exchange">>},
                           'x-delayed-message',true,false,false,
                           [{<<"x-delayed-type">>,longstr,<<"topic">>}],
                           undefined,undefined,
                           {[],[]}}],
                         [{file,
                           "src/rabbit_exchange_type_delayed_message.erl"},
                          {line,61}]},
                        {rabbit_exchange,declare,6,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_exchange.erl"},{line,165}]},
                        {rabbit_channel,handle_method,3,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,1234}]},
                        {rabbit_channel,handle_cast,2,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_channel.erl"},{line,470}]},
                        {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,
                         [{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1047}]},
                        {proc_lib,wake_up,3,
                         [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}'

=INFO REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:28 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1308.0> (127.0.0.1:47419 -> 127.0.0.1:5672 - connectionFactory#8139c95:5, vhost: '/', user: 'admin')

=INFO REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:28 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1330.0> (127.0.0.1:47421 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:29 ===
Connection <0.1330.0> (127.0.0.1:47421 -> 127.0.0.1:5672) has a client-provided name: connectionFactory#8139c95:6

=INFO REPORT==== 31-May-2019::09:03:29 ===
connection <0.1330.0> (127.0.0.1:47421 -> 127.0.0.1:5672 - connectionFactory#8139c95:6): user 'admin' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what versions of software you're using, and what RabbitMQ logs at the time of this error.

Comment: @LukeBakken Please see my edit. I've added the logs. I'm using rabbitmq 3.6 on production, though I used the latest 3.7 on local environment. I've also enabled the delay message plugin.